# Fetch records from same table by 2 applications

Tags: java, oracle

I have an Oracle DB table where I have some records, that should be fetched by 2 instances of application to do some actions on the data. both instances will query same table at the same time. how can I make sure that the 2 instances will not fetch same records.

im trying to achieve high availability  solution by that, so in case 1 instance failed other will keep working.

Comment: SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED might be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Provide information about what you want to do with fetching rows. For example, you can allocate rows between some processes with update (set process number before fetch data any process). Also you can use for update clause by some condition.

Comment: lets assume the master table have 1000 requests, and 3 instances of 1 application accessing the table to fetch the records, move them to another table as already processed records. the problem here that lock can happen if all accessing the same data

Comment: @MohammadAlnaimat what should do with data each process ? Delete? Update? How need process data? You can select data by each application in cursor statement with FOR UPDATE clause. If you need processed equal portion by each application you can slice data before. For example add field ProcNo and update somewhere before pass data to some processes.

Answer (score 0):

I have to confess that I have not (yet) tested this, but how about doing something like:

```
select blah..
from table
for update of ...
skip locked rows
```

Comment: Thank you, i have tried that. the problem in enterprise applications. 1 process will lock the records for update, 2nd and 3rd will try to access same records and will keep waiting for the lock to be released. and that is waste of time.

Comment: It should not lock the same rows. Can you provide evidence that it does?